# Prompt Touch ID without passcode fallback before SecItemAdd in Keychain

Tags: ios, swift, keychain, touch-id, localauthentication

I would like to prompt Touch ID without passcode fallback before allowing the user to store in the keychain.

I know that setting SecAccessControlCreateFlags.touchIDCurrentSet when storing will force this to happen when the user asks for an item in the Keychain (SecItemCopyMatching).

It seems impossible to do it with LocalAuthentication and I cannot find the way to do it with SecAddItem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also trying to work this with LocalAuthentication and seems no help yet.